# SharePoint 2010 permissions showing as applied but not taking effect

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, permissions

I have a SP2010 On-premises setup here and recently used stadm to enable the people-picker to resolve users from a trusted domain. This is now resolving fine, however, I've added a test user from this domain to the Contribute SP group but cannot login to the site, it just repeatedly prompts for credentials. I've used the "Check Permissions" tool and SP is reporting that this user has Contribute and Limited Access through relevant groups so as far as it's concerned I should be able to log in but I can't.

Removing this user from this group is reflected in the results of this tool as expected.

I've left this overnight to make sure it's not just down to a timing issue but doesn't look to be the case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sometimes I face this issue. The first thing I do is to check whether user's userID and Password is correct, not locked. And most of the times it comes as password is locked. Hope this helps.

Comment: User account isn't locked. I'm currently logged into Windows as this user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this to work. The last piece of the puzzle was that two of the SP services (SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service and Subscription Settings Service) weren't running within the SP Central Administration Console. Having just taken this environment on I didn't think these were critical to the process as hadn't stopped them myself but turns out they did need to be running.

So to summarize I had to:

- Reset the SharePoint cache - http://www.sharepointgeoff.com/usage-data-import-job-fail-8075-and-execute-method-spusageimportjobdefinition-fail-6398-%E2%80%93-how-to-fix/
- Service password - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2012/01/10/retrieving-the-com-class-factory-for-component-with-clsid-office14-0005-0000-0000-000000000000-failed-due-to-the-following-error-8007042d/
- Reset this password within SP also using the SP Management Shell with the following command "Set-SPManagedAccount -UseExistingPassword"
- Default website in IIS wasn't running. Don't think this is critical but couldn't see why it was stopped.
- SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service and Subscription Settings Service were both in a stopped state. Restarted and STS errors in Application event log disappeared.

My users are now authenticating but further testing is needed to make sure this is definitely the case.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite probable you have a time difference between your Sharepoint servers domain  and the trusted domain if you have access to the trusted DC log in and compare. If you can't access trusted DC try to enable the Netlogon Event viewer should give you a bit more information. Checking the Security Audit events on the Sharepoint server should give you the information as well.

Comment: Time is spot on between the two so isn't this issue in this instance. There are a number of errors in the Application event log for SP Foundation so will investigate these and see if they're relevant.

Comment: It seems your problem is happening before even reaches Sharepoint properly. I try to use wireshark to capture the auth session for the user. Have you tried any another user from that trusted AD?

Comment: I'm just going through many critical and error events within the Application log before I go any further with this. Should have looked here first as dare say the cause is to do with these. I'll report back with my findings.

Comment: Ok, I've now cleared up any critical errors that were showing in the Central Administration console and event viewer. I'm now only left with a couple of alerts that are complaining that "Accounts used by application pools or service identities are in the local machine administrators group" which I will address but don't think is a cause of my initial problem.

Comment: I addressed STS, COM Class and SharePoint cache issues which all seemed relevant and now have a nice clean event log but still can't log into the site with these credentials. Any further ideas?